# Too many arguments error in multiple nested IF and AND statements

Tags: excel

I have an issue with a multiple nested IF statement. I have multiple columns I'm referring to.

The logic is such:

```
If response by = "No response required" then blank
If allocation days <2, "target achieved" else "target missed", 
If allocation days < 1 AND date allocated = blank, "target on track" else "target missed",
If allocation days <=1 AND date allocated = not blank, "target achieved" else "target missed"
```

The formula i have so far is :

```
IF([RESPONSE BY]="NO RESPONSE REQUIRED","",  IF([@[Allocation days]]<2,"Target Achieved","Target Missed"),  IF(AND([@[Allocation days]]<1,[@[Date allocated]]=""),"Target On Track","Target Missed"),   IF(AND([@Allocation days]]<=1,COUNTA[@[Date allocated]]), "Target Achieved", "Target Missed")
```

The code works till the second IF statement and after that excel says there's too many arguments for this function. Would appreciate any help, I'm new to this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of all but the last `,"Target Missed")` and add the `)` to the end.

```
=IF([@[RESPONSE BY]]="NO RESPONSE REQUIRED","",IF(AND([@[Allocation Days]]<=1,COUNTA([@[Date Allocated]])),"Target Achieved",IF(AND([@[Allocation Days]]<1,[@[Date Allocated]]=""),"Target On Track", IF([@[Allocation Days]]<2, "Target Achieved", "Target Missed"))))
```

Comment: Hey Scott, thanks for your suggestion. I gave it a go and still got the same error. The problem seems to be in the first AND statement according to excel's function argument tool.

Comment: @ruswr please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.